# Deploy Ionic App as Website

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular, ionic-framework

I needed to know whether ionic app can be deployed as a website or not? If yes are there any security issues or impediments in doing so? Please share the steps or link for the same.

Thanks,

Comment: Ionic basically is a webapp that is deployed on some device like Android or iOS, and to develop them you must deploy them as a webpage

Answer (score 0):

Just put a `www` folder on your web server, and put in an `<iframe>` like this to showcase your app demo:

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/myapp/" width="320" height="568"></iframe>
```

Comment: And yes you'll require to make changes in source if any of plugins are used.